# Why are the periodic solutions of conservative unidimensional systems symmetrical regarding the $x$ axis?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the equation
$$
x''=F(x)
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\begin{array}{l}
x'=v\\
v'=F(x)
\end{array}
$$
I have already shown that all the equilibrium points of the system are on the $x$ axis, and that all the periodic orbits of it intersect the $x$ axis.

How do I show that the periodic orbits are symmetrical with respect to the $x$ axis? Can I solve this using the fact that the Total Energy of the system is a first integral for it?

Comment: Do you have a formula for F(x) ? For symmetry, you would want to show that substituting -y for y doesn't change the equation.

Comment: I've tried that to no result. Also, I don't have F; it must be assumes as a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation as :

$\frac{dx}{dv}=\frac{v}{F(x)}$

Then integrating, you get

$v^2(x)/2=\int_0^x F(p)dp$

Hence, for every value of $x$, you have a +v and -v value of $v(x)$. Hence there is symmetry w.r.t to x-axis

Comment: Well done :) Thanks!